Google Classroom API: courses.courseWork.list returning empty object
I am currently signed in as a student authenticated with the API scopes
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.course-work.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.student-submissions.me.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.courseworkmaterials.readonly",
".../auth/classroom.topics.readonly"

(the ...s were included so SO wouldn't flag this as spam).
but when I fetch the courses.courseWork.list endpoint at https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/:id/courseWork (with :id replaced with the actual id, of course), I get 200 OK with a JSON body of empty object {} in response. Requesting other endpoints such as announcements and courseWorkMaterials return the expected response for the same course id. Am I doing something wrong here or is the endpoint broken? The classes I am requesting course work for have assignments, so there should be no reason that the response is empty.
So far I have tried many combinations of scopes, multiple different classroom classes, and even tried on the API explorer (which also returns an empty object). I test all my requests through Insomnia.

Are the assignments in the PUBLISHED state? Assignments in other states don't appear for students in LIST requests https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list. Are the assignments assigned to that particular student?
